# Convert from ArrayList<String[]> to Collection<Object[]>?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a method that must return a Collection of Arrays. (It's a parameterized test in JUnit.) I actually only need to return three strings, but they need to be in a Collection of Arrays. This is my method:

```
public static Collection<Object[]> browserList() {
    String[] firefox = { "firefox" };
    String[] chrome = { "chrome" };
    String[] ie = { "ie" };
    ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>(3);
    list.add(firefox);
    list.add(chrome);
    list.add(ie);
    return list;
}
```

This gives an error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String[]> to Collection<Object[]>`.

So really two questions: (a) what is wrong with this, considering that `ArrayList` is an implementation of `Collection` and `String` is derived from `Object`; and (b) how would I fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java collections covariance problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763192/java-collections-covariance-problem)

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableList` would work to view an `ArrayList<String[]>` as an `ArrayList<Object[]>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first question, [a `Collection <String []>` is not a `Collection <Object []>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit) because generics are not polymorphic.

For your second question, simply declare everything as objects:

```
public static Collection<Object[]> browserList() {
    Object[] firefox = { "firefox" };
    Object[] chrome = { "chrome" };
    Object[] ie = { "ie" };
    ArrayList<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>(3);
    list.add(firefox);
    list.add(chrome);
    list.add(ie);
    return list;
}
```

Which you could condense in:

```
public static Collection<Object[]> browserList() {
    Object[] firefox = { "firefox" };
    Object[] chrome = { "chrome" };
    Object[] ie = { "ie" };

    return Arrays.asList(firefox, chrome, ie);
}
```