# Add subclasses to ConcurrentHashMap of super type in a static initializer?

Tags: java, static, hashmap

```
public class People {

    class Family extends People {

    }

}


public class Together {
    private static Collection<Family> familyList = new ArrayList<Family>();
    private static ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<People>> registry = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<People>>();

    static {
        registry.put(Family.class.toString(), familyList); 
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
The method put(String, Collection<people>) in the type Map<String,Collection<people>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Collection<family>)
```

Why can't I put `familyList` into `registry`?  I figure that since `family` extends`people` that i should be able to place the sub types into the super type `registry` .

EDIT:  The above is solved.  My last part of the question involves a more complicated example using the same names:

```
public class Together {
    private static ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<Family>> familyMap= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<Family>>();
    private static ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<People>>> registry2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<People>>>();

    static {
        registry2.put(Family.class.toString(), familyMap); 
    }
}
```

(I already tried changing the declaration of `registry2` to having `?extends People`

Now the error is:
`The method put(String, ConcurrentMap<String,Collection<People>>) in the type Map<String,ConcurrentMap<String,Collection<People>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ConcurrentMap<String,Collection<Family>>)`

Comment: Classnames should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3763192/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2660850/139010

Comment: The second problem is the same as the first. The solution should be:

private static ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<? extends People>>> registry2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<? extends People>>>();

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work for me.  I will post this in a new question.  If you can answer it there, you could get the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

*people.java*

```
public class people {

    public class family extends people {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        together t = new together();
        System.out.println(together.registry);
    }

}
```

*together.java*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

public class together {
    private static Collection<people.family> familyList = new ArrayList<people.family>();
    public static ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<? extends people>> registry = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<? extends people>>();

    static {
        registry.put(people.family.class.toString(), familyList);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for making this clear!  I edited the question and will no doubt consult your answer for the first part of my question!

Comment: Great. I'm glad I could help. If this solution helped please select this as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Because a `Collection<family>` is not a `Collection<people>`. Put another way: [Java collections are not covariant.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2660850/139010)

> Is there a way I could put family into the hashmap?

Declare it as a `Collection<people>`.

Comment: Is there a way I could put family into the hashmap?

Comment: @StephenD declare it as a `Collection<people>`.

Answer (score 3):

`family`  is convertible to `people`, but `Collection<family>` is not convertible to `Collection<people>`.
Had it been convertible, you would have been able to unsafely add a different derived tyupe to the casted collection.

Instead, you can use a covariant view of the collection type:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<? extends people>>
```

Comment: @StephenD: Which this? Safe against what?

Comment: I'm not sure what I meant...  haha