# Overriding method needs to convert from List<ChildClass> to List<ParentClass>

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm mocking some code for testing. In one mock, I'm trying to mock `ServletFileUpload::parseRequest`, which returns a List of FileItems.

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

    private class MockServletFileUpload extends ServletFileUpload {

        List<MockDiskFileItem> fileItems;

        @Override
        public List<FileItem> parseRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return fileItems;
        }
    }
```

but Eclipse signals an error on the method's return: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<MockDiskFileItem> to List<FileItem>`. But `MockDiskFileItem implements FileItem`! Why doesn't this work?

On the other hand, this version of the method, which casts the individual elements of the List to the parent class, doesn't give errors:

```
    @Override
    public List<FileItem> parseRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return fileItems.stream()
                .map( dfi -> (FileItem) dfi )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Why do the elements have to be individually cast? And is there any shorter way to write this?

## UPDATE

To clarify, my question is primarily a practical one: how to convert/cast from `List<MockDiskFileItem>` to `List<FileItem>` most efficiently. I'd also like to know why Java can't automatically do the conversion/cast of the whole list, when as should be clear to anyone who takes the time to read the second version of the method, Java *will* automatically convert/cast any `MockDiskFileItem` to `FileItem`.

## UPDATE 2

I actually have an answer to my own question that shows why this question is different and not a duplicate. And you can see from the one answer below how this is a different question. Why was this closed? You moderators are too heavy handed. How many reputation points did that gain you? And what did it cost this site's integrity?

Comment: [Related - covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763192/java-collections-covariance-problem)

Comment: QBrute and StuartLC - it seems to me that OP understands very well that a `List<FileItem>` and a `List<MockDiskFileItem>` are not the same thing.  He's asking for code to convert one to the other, not an explanation of why they are different.

Comment: Why do you declare `fileItems` as `List<MockDiskFileItem>`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, in my mock, I need some additional methods on `MockDiskFileItem` that `FileItem` and `DiskFileItem` don't have.

Comment: Yes, they often close questions and mark them as duplicate when they're not. When there's more to the question than the suggested duplicate answer. I clearly dislike the superficiality that has taken hold with a lot of the "moderators". Most have established a routine of "maintaining" this site, and this is not good for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this, you'll get no errors:

```
public List<? extends FileItem> parseRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    return fileItems;
}
```

As above comments said, you have a problem with contravariance, and that generics are not covariant.

### Update

Oh yes, I completely forgot he's overriding a method. Sorry for that.
This is IMO the easiest and most efficient conversion with the least lines:

```
class MockServletFileUpload extends ServletFileUpload {

    List<MockDiskFileItem> fileItems;

    @Override public List<FileItem> parseRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new ArrayList<>(fileItems);
    }



    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final MockServletFileUpload msfu = new MockServletFileUpload();
        msfu.fileItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            msfu.fileItems.add(new MockDiskFileItemImpl());
        }


        final List<FileItem> result = msfu.parseRequest(null);
        System.out.println("Results:");
        System.out.println(result.getClass());
        for (final FileItem fileItem : result) {
            System.out.println("\t" + fileItem.getClass());
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

Up until quite a high amount if items (I guess 20k+) this will also be way faster than streams or parallel streams.

I added some simple test code to prove the items are still `MockDiskFileItem`s (or my implementation of it).

### Explanation

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po) is helpful to see the problem, but here's a little summary. Casting a generic like `List<ChildClass> foo` to `List<ParentClass> bar`

```
List<ChildClass> foo = new ArrayList<>();
List<ParentClass> bar = (List<ParentClass>) foo; // Doesn't work
```

would just create an alias to the same object in memory (same pointer), but treat it as a list consisting of elements of a different type. The danger is that objects of a sibling/other child type could then be added to this list whose elements are really the first child type. The classic example given:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
List<Animal> animals = dogs; // doesn't work because ...
animals.add(new Cat()); // ... BIG problem
```

Hopefully, you can see the problem in that last line!

To avoid the danger of adding a Cat to a Dog List, what you really need is a new list, converted, so to speak, to the parent element type. So you'll see the solution above makes a **copy** of the original list with the cast (implicit) to the parent type.

Comment: I don't think this will help, when OP is trying to override a base class where `parseRequest` returns `List<FileItem>`.  He really needs to convert his `List<MockDiskFileItem>` to a `List<FileItem>`, not just use a weaker data type.

Comment: @JayC667, I'm overriding a method in an established class, so changing the return type is not possible.

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableList()` should also work. If a client using this method expects to be able to alter the returned list, s/he will be screwed just as with the copied list; the only difference is that this throws an exception whereas a copied list just might not do what the client wants.

Comment: @Izruo While your solution is also good, actually I cannot see the problem that you address in my solution. I did an "upcast" of the contained elements, so they're actual `FileItem`s. I know there'd be problems if we had used downcasts, then we'd run into `ClassCastException`s and the like. Can you give me an example where my solution would cause an exception? (Unless he down-casts the list again somewhere...)

Comment: With *this throws an exception* I was referring to `Collections.unmofiableList()`. The scenario I'm thinking about is that a client expects to alter the behavior of the class by manipulating the returned list. In the code given by OP, this would affect consecutive calls of the `#parseRequest` method, in the code given in this answer, this would have no affect.